# Why does the pion live in a representation of isospin SU(2) and is the mediator of the strong force generated by color SU(3)?

Tags: standard-model, group-theory, strong-force, isospin-symmetry, pions

Why does the pion live in a representation of isospin $\rm SU(2)$ and is the mediator of the strong force generated by color $\rm SU(3)$?

I somehow find strange that this is the case. Given that $\rm SU(2)$ and $\rm SU(3)$ are different groups with different representations, I find it very strange that a particle living in one group is so important for the force created by another group.

Comment: Why is that strange? Groups are not mutually exclusive. Quarks transform as SU(3) color triplets, SU(2) weak doublets, and also carry U(1) hypercharge.

Comment: Related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9663/85745

Answer (score 4):

> Why the pion lives in a representation of isospin SU(2)

Sure, it is well described as a part of the [meson octet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_way_(physics)). That is how the quarks were discovered. Do not forget that SU(2) is a subgroup of an SU(3), in this case weak SU(3).

> and is the mediator of the strong force

It is a mediator in some of  the  models of the *strong **nuclear***  force

> generated by color SU(3)

The [strong nuclear force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_force)  is not generated, it *emerges* from the spill over of the color SU(3), similar to the spill over electric forces that  are part of the explanation of the [binding of the atoms and molecules into solids.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force)

Answer (score 2):

Given that color is confined, any "long-lived" resonance has to be an $SU(3)$ singlet. Pions are no exception. A pion is effectively a condensation of a left-handed quark and a right-handed antiquark. The color $SU(3)$ is non-chiral, meaning left-handed and right-handed fermions carry the same $SU(3)$ charge, thus the $SU(3)$ charges net out in a quark-antiquark pair. That being said, pions are the bound state of the strong force, thus you can deduce some color-related information by whacking them around.

On the other hand, the electroweak interaction is not confining, thus you could have $SU(2)$ singlets, doublets, or what have ya. Given that left-handed quarks carry weak $SU(2)$ charge and right-hand quarks don't, a pion as a left- and right-handed pair can NOT be an $SU(2)$ singlet.

Comment: Confinement is irrelevant.  SU(2) singlets and doublets can exist even in [strongly confined SU(2) models](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.34.873).  The indistinguishability of color charges comes from unbroken SU(3) gauge symmetry, not confinement.  The SM's SU(2) doublet states can only be isolated because the symmetry is broken (with differing proton & neutron masses, electron & neutrino properties, etc).