# What is the actual carrier of the strong force?

Tags: nuclear-physics, strong-force, carrier-particles, pions

I have been digging into the particle physics recently and I have found two different answers for this question. First of all, according to Wikipedia the Pion is a meson that acts as the carrier particle of the strong force and it is also classified as a boson with spin 0.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion

Of course, this is not only what I found in wikipedia but I also found this statement in books like Krane's Introductory Nuclear Physics. However, this doesn't make sense to me. How is a particle made of a quark (up) and an antiquark (down) make a boson? I guess it is by the total spin momentum but there are other properties as well that need to be checked. And finally, aren't gluons the actuals carries of the stron nuclear force?

Comment: Search terms: "residual strong force," "color singlet."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a composite boson like the pion be an exchange particle for the strong nuclear force?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/593929/)

Comment: *there are other properties as well that need to be checked* No. The [spin–statistics theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin–statistics_theorem) states that “integer-spin particles are bosons, while half-integer–spin particles are fermions”.

Comment: *Aren't gluons the actuals carriers of the strong nuclear force?* Yes, between quarks.

Comment: for the ones who have answered, my nuclear and particle physics course lastested in total 2 months due to stupid academic and potilitical reasons. The pther two months were spent in a useless full course in Quantum Chemistry and Spectroscopy