# Excitation of nucleus in radioactive decay

Tags: radioactivity

When I say that a nucleus is unstable, does this mean that the nucleus is in its excited state?

Comment: Yes, but only in the case of gamma-decay. In alpha decays, the nucleus is unstable as the ratio of mass number to atomic number is too high; in beta decay, the ratio is too low.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149400/what-makes-a-nucleus-unstable This should help you.